# Custom transparent UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbar

I am trying to create an app in which the tab bar transparent (or which looks transparent). For this i'm using part of an image in the view. And set the remaining part as background for tab bar. The problem is the tab bar appears with a darker shade. I'm out of ideas now.
Below is the screen shot

[image]

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_bg.png"]];
self.tabBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.tabBar insertSubview:imgView atIndex:1];
//    [self.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transp.png"]];
//    [self.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transp.png"]];
```

The above is the code that i've tried out in the `viewDidLoad` of my custom `UITabBarController` class. "tabbar_bg.png" is the image used as background for the tab bar and 'transp.png' is a transparent image used as the selectionIndicator image.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what's d use of tabbar when it's transparent.... user will never know about it.

Comment: only the tab bar is transparent. the tab bar item images will be visible giving it a floating effect.

Comment: self.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor ClearColor]; wont do the trick?

Comment: you can also set the alpha of the uitabbar [self.tabBar setAlpha:0.5]; this will make it translucent. you can set it to 0.3 or 0.2 as per your choice. 0 will make it transparent and 1 will bring it back to the original state. I hope it helps.

Comment: alpha 0 will make it's inner controls transparent as well.... i suggest u to try solution given by prajwal

Comment: Nope none of this works. I've tried all that to make the tab bar transparent.

Comment: did u solve this? I am facing same issue. Let me know

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```

This trick also works for `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a subclass of it?

```
@implementation TabBarInvisible
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.backgroundImage = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

}

@end
```